# Using cmake on macOS force building shared libraries in .so version instead of .dylib

Tags: macos, gcc, cmake, shared-libraries

I have a problem with forcing building shared libraries on macOS in typical .so standard way for GNU GCC compiler. I force to use GCC instead of Clang compiler, but CMake still produce .dylib instead of .so. Can anybody tell me, how can I force to create so instead of dylib, because my lib need to have .so version?

Answer (score 0):

did you try `CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX` ?
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX.html